# Given an array of strings, write a function that returns an array of objects representing each unique string and its frequency in the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, reduce

I want to print the string and the frequency of it as an object stored inside an array. I have been using only reduce method to do so and want result through the same method only, Can anyone tell me what should I rectify in the below code:

```
const strings = ["pink", "red", "pink", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow"];

const frequencyOfStrings = (arrayOfStrings) => {
  return arrayOfStrings.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr]) {
      acc[curr]++;
    } else {
      acc[curr] = 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
};

console.log(frequencyOfStrings(strings));
```

I am getting output as:

```
[ pink: 2, red: 1, yellow: 3 ]
```

Whereas I want my output as:

```
[{ string: 'pink', frequency: 2 }, { string: 'red', frequency: 1 }, { string: 'yellow', frequency: 3 }]
```

P.S - I am a beginner at Javascript with no knowledge of time-complexities, as of now.

Comment: For that specific output, using only `reduce()` is perfectly possible but wildly inefficient (`O(n log n)`). Better to reduce to an object and then use `Object.entries()` and `map()` to get to your output format (`O(n)`).

Comment: Might even be O(n * n)

Comment: @Eureka Agree. Depends on the distribution of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired output format, you need to modify the reduce function to return an array of objects instead of an object.
Here is the updated code

```js
const strings = ["pink", "red", "pink", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow"];

const frequencyOfStrings = (arrayOfStrings) => {
  return Object.entries(
    arrayOfStrings.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (acc[curr]) {
        acc[curr]++;
      } else {
        acc[curr] = 1;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {})
  ).map(([string, frequency]) => ({ string, frequency }));
};

console.log(frequencyOfStrings(strings));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a `foreach` to do the job, but you can use `reduce` and you need to change the logic inside it.

In your desired output you want an `array` of `objects`, so inside your `reduce`, you need to look for the right `object` in your output `array` then update its `frequency`, if it matches your `current` element, otherwise add a new element with `1` as `frequency`.

This is how should be your code:

```
const frequencyOfStrings = (arrayOfStrings) => {
  return arrayOfStrings.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let foundIndex = acc.findIndex(el => el["string"] === curr);
    if (foundIndex >= 0) {
      acc[foundIndex].frequency++;
    } else {
      acc.push({
        "string": curr,
        "frequency": 1
      })
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
};
```

**Demo:**

```js
const strings = ["pink", "red", "pink", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow"];

const frequencyOfStrings = (arrayOfStrings) => {
  return arrayOfStrings.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let foundIndex = acc.findIndex(el => el["string"] === curr);
    if (foundIndex >= 0) {
      acc[foundIndex].frequency++;
    } else {
      acc.push({
        "string": curr,
        "frequency": 1
      })
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
};

console.log(frequencyOfStrings(strings));
```

Comment: Like I said in my comment to the question: wildly inefficient. This one even has a potential runtime complexity of `O(n^3)`. Could at least reduce it to `O(n^2)` by getting rid of the `some()` and base your logic on the result of `find()`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes you are right, that's what I was thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you insist on using a tool (`reduce`) which is obviously not appropriate for the job? Just use a loop:

```
const frequencyOfStrings = (arrayOfStrings) => {
    let m = new Map

    for (let string of arrayOfStrings)
        if (m.has(string))
            m.get(string).frequency += 1
        else
            m.set(string, {string, frequency: 1})

    return [...m.values()]
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with using `reduce()`. It's definitely appropriate for the job. The problem is with *only* using `reduce()`. Your solution could easily be rewritten with `reduce()` without detracting from its elegance or performance.